# how to check with boolean if input is integer even casting input as integer

Tags: python-3.x

I am failing at an optional task where i check the input of `int(input("my string"))` with .isdigit()

without this optional task i solved task but i want to learn efficient so i need your help guys.

**The task**

> get input of 2 integer numbers
>       cast the input and print the input followed by the result
>       Output Example: 9 + 13 = 22
>
> > Optional: check if input .isdigit() before trying integer addition to avoid errors in casting invalid inputs

**My code so far**

```
int_nmbr1 = int(input("Enter first number: "))
int_nmbr2 = int(input("Enter second number: "))
if int_nmbr1.isdigit() & int_nmbr2.isdigit() == True: #Here i check it with is.digit() twice
print(int_nmbr1, " + ", int_nmbr2, " = ", int_nmbr1 + int_nmbr2)
```

**Console Error Output**

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
      3 int_nmbr2 = int(input("Enter second number: ")) 
      4 
----> 5 if int_nmbr1.isdigit() & int_nmbr2.isdigit() == True:
      6     print(int_nmbr1, " + ", int_nmbr2, " = ", int_nmbr1 + int_nmbr2)

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isdigit'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re trying to implement `isdigit` on `int` data type while it is a method of `str`. 
By using `int(input())`, your input is already an `int` value if you enter any value with base10. So you don’t need to use `isdigit`. `isdigit` is used to check if it is any digit in string format.
If you’ve still any doubt, you can check `dir(str)` and `dir(int)`. And furthermore, you can check the `print(help(str.isdigit))`.

And now, in case of wrong data type entered, you can use `exception handelings`.
You can use it like this:

```
try:
    int(input(“enter any number:”))
except ValueError:
    print(“Please enter any integer value only”)
    int(input(“enter any number:”))
```

Above code will not return error if you’ll enter any other data type instead of integer for first time.